# Create SVG and Rectangle not working

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm trying to create a simple library to draw with SVG on HTML. While the code generates valid HTML that does draw what I want, when I do this programatically, nothing is drawn in the screen. Here's the code that I'm using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="diagram"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function Diagram(div) {
      div = document.getElementById(div);
      svg = document.createElement("svg");
      svg.setAttribute("width", "600");
      svg.setAttribute("height", "400");
      div.appendChild(svg);

      this.diagram = svg;
      this.rectangle = function (x, y, width, height) {
        rect = document.createElement("rect");
        rect.setAttribute("x", x);
        rect.setAttribute("y", y);
        rect.setAttribute("width", width);
        rect.setAttribute("height", height);
        this.diagram.appendChild(rect);
      }
    }

      var diagram = new Diagram("diagram");
      diagram.rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Needless to say, I'm not experienced with JS and I'm using this as an exercise in both learning JS and SVG, but I was unable to understand why my example is not working :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating SVG elements, you'd use `createElementNS` to create elements with a qualified namespace, like SVG elements

```
document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
```

and for certain attributes you'd use `setAttributeNS`, but for regular attributes like width and height, `setAttribute` should work

```
svg.setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xlink", "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink");
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5m5udg3v/)

Comment: Cool! works as a charm. Can you point me to some documentation to understand why this is needed and how this works? Thanks!

Comment: @vainolo - [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElementNS) is usually helpful